Is it possible to bake normals for multiple similar objects using single high poly?
I’m trying to find the way to bake all teeth (see picture) from one single high poly tooth. Is it possible?
Teeth were made with array and curve modifiers. Modifiers were applied as the lower ones was deformed too much and needed manual adjustment. I tried to use curve without deformation too, but didn’t liked the result, so it was shrugged away.
Copy UV maps from one tooth to rest, didn’t gave any positive result.
So give me pls advice on how to do it, or what is a proper workflow in such cases.


If possible, please attach an illustration of the final product, etc., to help inspire the respondent. Also, if possible, attach the Blender file along with it. Thank you.。https://blend-exchange.com/

Ok, I kinda managed to do it, but…

Unwrap model while it still has Array on it, so that after it been applied isles would be stacked on top of each other.
Separate single tooth, the one which corresponds to high poly.
Exported LP model with only this single tooth to substance.
Baked.
Re-exported LP model with all teeth.

It seem like some terrible way of doing it, and there must be something more sane.

